# Cannot retrieve company preferences

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

How can I fetch company preferences?

The [API documentation page](http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/Preference) for retrieving preferences is buggy. The entire content of the "Sample Retrieve Request XML" section is:

```
&nbsp;&nbsp; &lt;/IntuitRequest&gt;
```

Simple posts and gets to the documented URI do not work:

```
HTTP Status 404 - Null subresource for path: https://services.intuit.com/sb/preferences/v2/561234567
The requested resource (Null subresource for path: https://services.intuit.com/sb/preferences/v2/561234567) is not available.
```

Comment: Did you include the OAuth header when you made the request?

Answer (score 2):

The endpoint should be preference instead of preference**s**.

https://services.intuit.com/sb/preference/v2/[[realmId]]

You can send a GET request or a POST with an empty body.  I will look into the docs issue.

You can also test the call in API Explorer: http://apiexplorer.developer.intuit.com/V2QBD#api